# How to edit key value

Tags: javascript

I have the following object

```js
var CUSTOMER = {
        tite: 'Mr',
        first: 'Andy',
        last: 'Smith',
        Date: '10',
        Month: '01'
    };
```

and I need to change it so that Date and month is a single key and combine the Date and Month together with a '-'. Like so

```js
var CUSTOMER = {
        tite: 'Mr',
        first: 'Andy',
        last: 'Smith',
        dob: '10-01'
    };
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you already manage to solve it in a way that you think is not the "easiest"? If so, could you please add it to the question so people can compare your variant with the rest of the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use + operator and concat() to resolve this

```js
var CUSTOMER = {
        tite: 'Mr',
        first: 'Andy',
        last: 'Smith',
        Date: '10',
        Month: '01'
    };

CUSTOMER.dob = CUSTOMER.Date + '-'.concat(CUSTOMER.Month);
delete CUSTOMER.Date;
delete CUSTOMER.Month;
console.log(CUSTOMER);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CUSTOMER.dob = CUSTOMER.Date + '-' + CUSTOMER.Month;
delete CUSTOMER.Date;
delete CUSTOMER.Month;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an object literal and can create a new property on it and then assign the value as a concatenation of two other properties. Then, remove the `Date` and `Month` property from the Object literal using `delete` operator.

Also, not sure what you are trying to do, but it would be better to have a `Date` for the Date related properties as it it easier to get the month, date, year from the date Object, rather than relying on string manipulation.

```js
var CUSTOMER = {
        tite: 'Mr',
        first: 'Andy',
        last: 'Smith',
        Date: '10',
        Month: '01'
    };

CUSTOMER.dob = CUSTOMER.Date + "-" + CUSTOMER.Month;
delete CUSTOMER.Date;
delete CUSTOMER.Month;
console.log(CUSTOMER);
```

Comment: @Mikey - Glad it helped. please do not forget to mark the answer/upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var CUSTOMER = {
        tite: 'Mr',
        first: 'Andy',
        last: 'Smith',
        Date: '10',
        Month: '01'
    };
    
 CUSTOMER.dob = CUSTOMER.Date+"-"+CUSTOMER.Month;
 delete CUSTOMER.Date; // delete Date
 delete CUSTOMER.Month; //delete Month
 console.log(CUSTOMER);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var CUSTOMER = {
        tite: 'Mr',
        first: 'Andy',
        last: 'Smith',
        Date: '10',
        Month: '01'
    };

CUSTOMER.dob = CUSTOMER.Date.concat("-").concat(CUSTOMER.Month);
delete CUSTOMER.Date;
delete CUSTOMER.Month;
```

I prefer to use `concat` as it is more clear to what you're doing (appending strings, not doing math adding).